# Problema com EntityManager e JPA

Tags: java, jpa

estou com um problema aqui que diz que o entitymanager is closed...dei uma olhada na net pra seguir o mesmo modelo, mas aqui da errado...
esse é meu metodo entitymanager

```
private EntityManager getEntityManager(){
    EntityManagerFactory factory = null;
    EntityManager em = null;
    try{
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("afastamentoGuarnicao");
        em = factory.createEntityManager();
    }finally{
        em.close();
    }
    return em;
}
```

e esse é meu metodo para gravar...

```
    public boolean gravar(UsuarioArranchamento usuarioArranchamento) {
    EntityManager em = null;        
    if (usuarioArranchamento.getSenha2().equals(usuarioArranchamento.getSenha())) {
        try {
            em = getEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            if (usuarioArranchamento.getId() == 0) {
                em.persist(usuarioArranchamento);
            } else {
                em.merge(usuarioArranchamento);
            }
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            UtilMensagens.mensagemInfo("Cadastro realizado com sucesso!");
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            if (em.getTransaction().isActive() == false) {
                em.getTransaction().begin();
            }
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
            UtilMensagens.mensagemErro("Erro ao cadastrar: Usuario ja existente, por favor escolha outro.");
            return false;
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    } else {
        UtilMensagens.mensagemErro("Senhas diferentes.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

alguem sabe como resolver isso? muito obrigado

stracktrace do erro...

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.checkOpen(EntityManagerImpl.java:97)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.checkOpen(EntityManagerImpl.java:88)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.close(EntityManagerImpl.java:140)
at dao.UsuarioArranchamentoDAO.login(UsuarioArranchamentoDAO.java:97)
at control.ControlUsuarioArranchamento.efetuarLogin(ControlUsuarioArranchamento.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:279)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(Unknown Source)
... 26 more
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stackoverflow em português, seria bom você colocar o stacktrace da exception para sabermos a linha e o erro que deu.

Comment: ta ai cara, editei meu post...obrigado por responder...

Answer (score 1):

No seu método getentityManager você tem um `finally{ em.close(); }`. E é isso está fechando o seu entityManager.

Comment: sim cara, isso eu sei...preciso saber de uma solução para isso.

Comment: Ué, basta não fechá-lo... se o método existe para retornar um entitymanager não faz sentido fechá-lo, concorda?

Comment: certo...obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Transforme o `EntityManagerFactory` em uma variável no escopo de classe e não de método, já que você só vai precisar de uma para cada execução do programa, e faça a declaração diretamente.

```
private static EntityManagerFactory factory =
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnit");
```

Por fim, o problema está no próprio método que abre a conexão no `finally`, para resolver, apenas exclua-o do metodo `getEntityManager()` e deixe somente aquele que esta dentro do metodo `gravar()`.